# How to store foreign key in mongoose(mongodb)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Order table and a Attempt table. I wish to store the foreign keys of attempts in orders. I do in the following way

```
AttemptSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var attempt = this;
    Order.findById(this.order).exec(function(err, order) {
      if (err) next(err);
      if (!order) next(new Error('could not load order with order_id:' + order));
      order.attempts.push({    
        attempt: attempt,
        runsheet: attempt.runsheet
      });
      order.save(function(err){
        if(err) next(err);
        else next();
      });
    });
});
```

When I print the order it is prints following. Where are the extra _id and id comping from. Is there better way of storing this?

```
{
  "_id": "54a6522b528f452cebe9268c",
  "attempts": [
    {
      "attempt": "54a65d1721d6802c2b4eb04f",
      "runsheet": null,
      "_id": "54a65d1721d6802c2b4eb050",
      "id": "54a65d1721d6802c2b4eb050"
    }
  ]
}
```

Schemas of tables are as follows

```
var AttemptSchema = new Schema({
  order: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Order',
    required:'true',
    index: true
  },
  runsheet: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Runsheet'
  },
});

var OrderSchema = new Schema({
  attempts: [{
    attempt: {
      type: Schema.ObjectId, 
      ref: 'Attempt'
    },
    runsheet: {
      type: Schema.ObjectId, 
      ref: 'Runsheet'
    }
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct use case for async.series,and its not being used correctly.For traversing though an array of objects ,async.each will be a better choice.Try the below,it should solve your problem

```
AttemptSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var attempt = this;
    Order.findById(this.order).exec(function(err, order) {
        if (err) next(err);
        if (!order) next(new Error('could not load order with order_id:' + order));
        var isPresent = false;
        async.each(order.attempts, function(each_order_attempt, callback) {
            if (each_order_attempt._id === attempt._id) isPresent = true;
            callback();     //calls the next value of array object
        }, function(err) {  //called finally when all of them are done
            if (!isPresent) {
                order.attempts.push({
                    attempt: attempt,
                    runsheet: attempt.runsheet
                });
            }
            order.save(function(err) {
                if (err) next(err);
                else next();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I think for loop is most ideal since there is no db or fs query.

Comment: With for loops in node.js,the value of i needs to be used with a closure ,because its asynchronous i would be set to max value before it actaully finishes processing the inner loop.async.each is a much more elegant solution.Did you try it?Did it work?

Comment: I tried with for loop, async and infact you can skip that step and directly add attempt to order. It would still show 2 more properties in the attempts array in orders

Comment: Thats wierd.I hope you have cleared those 2 (extra_id and id) before trying to test again.Anyway after var attempt = this; could do a console.log in attempt.